# Get route url from root component

Tags: angular

In AppComponent, I'm trying to read the URL and the params  in `ngOnInit` and decide where to redirect the user.

I understand that the routes are not instantiated at that point, therefore which I get empty values.

I can use `setTimeout` but it is hacky and unreliable. Is there a better way to capture the url and params?

```
//app.component.ts
constructor(private router: Router) {
    //
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Get the url to redirect
      console.log(">>>> ", this.router.url);
    }, 200);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen router events and find out the NavigationEnd to perform url extractions instead of using setTimeOut.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       console.log(this.router.url);
    }
  });
}
```